# How do button not workable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got this html. So, i want what CreateWorld calles once. I think this is may do with JQuery function, such as disable(). But i don't know which.

```
<input type="button" value="Создать мир" onclick="CreateWorld()" class="create_button"/>
```

I need the button to fire the first time just click on it. I can create a counter. But I think there are any simple solutions. But I do not know what
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using jQuery, and want this function to be called once:

```
$('.create_button').one('click',function(){
    CreateWorld();
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/kRDAS/).

The above will allow the event handler to fire once.

Or:

```
$('.create_button').click(function(){
    CreateWorld;
    $(this).prop('disabled',true);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/kRDAS/1/).

This will allow the button to have a click handler to be assigned for every click but will, after it's been clicked once, disable the button (preventing it from receiving clicks/user interaction).

To use plain JavaScript (albeit requiring a standards-compliant browser):

```
function buttonActions (){
    CreateWorld();
    this.disabled = true;
}
document.querySelector('.create_button').addEventListener('click', buttonActions);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/kRDAS/2/).

References:

- [('Plain') JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript):

  - [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener).
  - [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector).
- [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/):

  - [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
  - [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).
  - [`one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/).

Comment: Thanks, good answet. Second example work only when i am call CreateWorld() not CreateWorld;. I am forgot access to jsfiddle and can't atach link. Very useful answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) it will only listen click event once

**HTML :**

```
<input type="button" value="Создать мир" class="create_button"/>
```

**JQUERY :**

```
$('input.create_button').one('click',CreateWorld);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('.create_button').on('click',function(){
        CreateWorld();
    $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.create_button').on('click',function(){
if($(this).hasClass('disabled')) return;
CreateWorld();
$(this).addClass('disabled');
```

});

So later if you are making ajax call u can remove class to make button to work

onSuccess : $('.create_button').removeClass('disabled');
onFaulure : $('.create_button').removeClass('disabled');